# Which version of SQLite should I use?

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I want to use the SQLite, but I am unsure which binary should I use with my visual studio 2013.
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

For example, what is the difference between the precompiled binary and percompiled static linked binary? And what about the NuGet packages?

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page that you so helpfully linked to actually contains the full answer to your question, if you read it carefully.

Look for the heading **Package Types**, which explains that the items available for download are the *source code*, the *setup packages*, and the *binary packages*. Read that section carefully to determine which of these you need.

That same page also explains the difference between precompiled binary and precompiled statically linked binary packages (*All the "static" packages contain either native or mixed-mode assembly binaries linked statically to the appropriate version of the Visual C++ runtime. **Typically, these packages are used in cases where customer machines may not have the necessary version of the Visual C++ runtime installed and it cannot be installed due to limited privileges.***).

[**NuGet** is "the" package manager for the Microsoft development platform including .NET](http://www.nuget.org/). A NuGet package seems to be self-explanatory.